# Tabs jquery without jquery UI

Tags: jquery

Does anyone have any resources about creating your own tab control without using jQuery UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a plugin.

**Tabs - jQuery plugin for accessible, unobtrusive tabs**
http://stilbuero.de/jquery/tabs/

You can google for "jQuery Tabs Plugin" if you don't like that one.

Comment: your link is broken, can you please check?

Comment: @Brock: This answer is a little more than "Google it!" First, it tells the OP to look for a plugin instead of creating his own.  Second it gives the name of a plugin along with a link.  That link is now dead, but you can still Google the name and find it.  Third, it gives another specific phrase to search for to find more plugins.

Answer (score 2):

To the point, tabs are nothing more than a few buttons (links?) which toggles the visibility (show/hide) of some panels (div's?). Knowing that, it should be straightforward enough to write your own tabbed panel. You can make use of specific names/patterns in the class or ID of the buttons and panels to relate them with each other and hide the other panels.